# How to program a Reverse Fibonacci generator

Tags: java, assembly, mips

I am trying to code a reverse fibonacci generator in MIPS Assembly language, but I'm really just looking for the logic so an answer in low level Java or C++ is understandable to me.

I can only use one sub-routine (function/method) and cannot store any of the values in the sequence.  This function needs to calculate and print the sequence.  Basically, I need to use a recursive function.  The user will provide a fibonacci number, and I need to generate output starting from that number and going down.  I have access to the n-th place the number is in the sequence for whatever value the user inputs. (i.e. 55 is the 10th fibonacci number)

I can code this in C++ with multiple function calls, but I'm having a ton of difficulty watering it down to MIPS Assembly language.  Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Duplicate: [SO Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MIPS+Recursive+Fibonacci+Sequence) is your friend, first hit: [MIPS Recursive Fibonacci Sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976456/mips-recursive-fibonacci-sequence)

Comment: I did search it, but that example is only interested in one data point, uses stacks, and isn't at all in reverse order.

Comment: you're right, my bad, what about this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515782/fibonacci-sequence

Comment: Why do you need to use a recursive function?  Why not just generate the sequence in a loop, and compare each generated sequence number to your input number?  There may even be a closed-form formula, since there is one for the Nth Fibonacci number.  IDK if it's invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the naive Fibonacci calculation is recursive, you need to store numbers.

It's not possible to be midway into n-th F(n) element calculation, and to get also F(n-2) and F(n-1) elements, as calculation of those will use the same CPU/registers, so the intermediate state of CPU has to be stored before F(n-2)/F(n-1) calls, and restored after, to continue with F(n) calculation.

Usually in such case the stack is used, but it's a memory and storing of intermediate results anyway. Even if you keep numbers only in CPU registers, it's still storage of values. So I'm not sure what are your real constraints in the task description, it's probably some specific way of number storing forbidden, otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

To reverse the process, like output `10` for `55` input (that's what you want?), you can actually go from F(1) upward, caching only last two results, and see when you hit/overrun input value.

Let's define sequence as: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1

Algorithm can be like:

1. read input
2. ; initialization of calculation
3. fake result F(n) = 1
4. F(n-1) = 0
5. F(n-2) uninitialized (in ASM just decide which register will be used to store it and write a comment)
6. n = 1
7. `fibonacciLoop:` ; main loop
8. if (input == F(n)), output "n" as result, exit (in ASM do "go to outputFound" and write the rest of code there, keeping `fibonacciLoop` short)
9. if (input < F(n)), output "input is between n-1 and n-th Fib number", exit (in ASM do "go to outputBetween"... as in previous step)
10. F(n-2) = F(n-1)
11. F(n-1) = F(n)
12. F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) (actually F(n) += F(n-2) reusing F(n) old value)
13. `inc` n  (increment: n = n + 1)
14. go to `fibonacciLoop`

Try to verify in head the algorithm looks OK and doing what you want, then to write it in ASM, check the CPU registers, if you can fit those intermediate values ( [`input`, `n`, `F(n)`, `F(n-1)`, `F(n-2)`] ) into registers ("allocate" them in your head), then write the instructions to execute each described step (I think most of them can be achieved by 1-2 CPU instructions already).

This algorithm is of course storing the F(n-2) and F(n-1) values, so it's breaking your description, if taken literally, but you can keep those in registers only, without storing it into memory.

---

edit: for input "1" it will always output "1", it's impossible to output "2". Rest of Fibonacci numbers are unique.

edit2: about "increment", just later I realized you are talking about MIPS, which is RISC-like (reduced instruction set computing), and as such doesn't have specialized +1 `inc` instruction, so indeed you should do the generic addition like `add r_with_n, r_with_n, #1` to do "n = n + 1".

Answer (score 0):

```
static void printReverseFib(const int max, const int f1 = 0, const int f2 = 1) {
    if (f2 <= max)
        printReverseFib(max, f2, f1 + f2);
    std::cout << f1 << ' ';
}

int main() {
    printReverseFib(55);
    return 0;
}
```

55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1 0